# Sort Map<String, Object> by keys with IgnoreCase?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, string-comparison, treemap

Well, I tested TreeMap but it doesn't take in account IgnoreCase on string comparision. I need to order lexicographically and ignoring case. Is there any other way?

Thanks, that works (TreeMap (Comparator c)). However, I have another question:

```
public final Comparator<Object> STR_IGN_CASE_COMP = new Comparator<Object>() {

    public int compare(Object h1, Object h2) {
            String s1 = h1.getId();
            String s2 = h2.getId();
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
}; //STR_IGN_CASE_COMP
```

How can I universialize the comparator to work with different objects? assuming all have the getId() method.

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Martin, it's not a good idea to completely change the question.  The next user with the privilege to do so (perhaps you) should revert it to its previous state.  Just post a new question!

Comment: +1, Agreed, when someone gives you an answer to your question, you should accept the answer and move on to a new question if one arises.

Comment: It would appear that the question has been "rolled forward" again, the question no longer matches any of the answers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You want to use a [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in the [`TreeMap` constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29).  In particular, look at [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).

```
TreeMap map = new TreeMap(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Using [`Collator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) or a custom `Comparator` may work better for you in a non-English locale or if you need more complex ordering.

Comment: Remember - if you're an english programmer, and you're in control of the keys you *don't* need to worry about locale, as comparisons aren't being done on the values, they're being done on the keys ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The best way would be to use a Collator.  A collator is a built in class, which also implements Comparable, and therefore you can use it for your TreeMap.

With a collator, you can also control the strength of the comparision, for example, if you want to be accent-insensitive as well.

```
Collator stringCollator = Collator.getInstance();
stringCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY); 
new TreeMap<String, String>(stringCollator)
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide it a Comparator that compares strings case ignored.

TreeMap(Comparator c)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I universialize the comparator
>   to work with different objects?
>   assuming all have the getId() method.

You should be able to use a [BeanComparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/).

Comment: I've recommended the question be reverted to the original question and a new question posted instead; if and when that happens, this answer ought probably to be removed too.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a list, I would say try Collections.sort() with a Comparator.  You may have to roll your own Comparator that uses String.equalsIgnoreCase() instead of equals().

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list,
                        Comparator<? super T> c)
```

But I was on the right track.  Try the TreeMap constructor that takes a Comparator:

```
public TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you want is to use the TreeMap constructor that takes a Comparator.  Make a comparator that uses compareToIgnoreCase.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you should construct your `TreeMap` with a custom comparator.

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Comparator;

class IgnoreCaseComp implements Comparator<String> {
  Collator col;

  IgnoreCaseComp() {
    col = Collator.getInstance();

    col.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
  }

  public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
    return col.compare(strA, strB);
  }
}
```